# One page check out Magento boxes greyed out - registered customers can't check out

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

when logged in customers go to our one page checkout all the boxes (billing, shipping, payment) are greyed out and you can't click them. What could be the cause of this? I am not sure from what date customers haven't been able to pay with the checkout.

We require customers to login when shopping.

I have tried flushing the cache but that made no difference.

We have Magento 1.7.0.2.

Comment: might be cause of div css overlap to all one step check out element. pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Liyakat. My developer has looked at it and fixed it. In Europe it seemed to work fine, it was just the Australian shop that was playing up. This is the thread he used to fix it: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/55232/P15/

Hope this will help others too!